# Use a nested array to create unique keys, and count values

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP I want to construct an array that uses the distinct `$raw['day']` as each row, and count up all the `$raw['delay']` that are greater than 0:

Start

```
$raw = array(
  [0] => ("day" => "2013-01-01", "delay" => 3),
  [1] => ("day" => "2013-01-01", "delay" => 16),
  [2] => ("day" => "2013-01-01", "delay" => 0),
  [3] => ("day" => "2013-01-02", "delay" => 1),
  [4] => ("day" => "2013-01-02", "delay" => 0),
  [5] => ("day" => "2013-01-03", "delay" => 9),
);
```

Result

```
array(
  [0] => ("day" => "2013-01-01", "misses" => 2),
  [1] => ("day" => "2013-01-02", "misses" => 1),
  [2] => ("day" => "2013-01-02", "misses" => 1),
)
```

What I've tried:

I was thinking first I'd get all unique days:

```
$all_days = array_column($raw, 'day');
$unique_days = array_unique($all_days);
```

Now that I've got all unique days, I can loop through `$raw` again and increment the misses.  But this seems overly verbose, and I figured among PHP's array functions there would be an easier solution.

```
foreach ($raw as $row) {
  if ($row['delay'] > 0) {
    $unique_days[$row['day']]++
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible approach:

```
$sum=array();
foreach ($raw as $r) {
    if ($r["delay"]>0) $sum[$r["day"]]++;
}
```

and then

```
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
 $sum[]=array("day"=>$k, "misses" => $v);
}
print_r($sum);
```

#### Test

```
$raw = array(
  0 => array("day" => "2013-01-01", "delay" => 3),
  1 => array("day" => "2013-01-01", "delay" => 16),
  2 => array("day" => "2013-01-01", "delay" => 0),
  3 => array("day" => "2013-01-02", "delay" => 1),
  4 => array("day" => "2013-01-02", "delay" => 0),
  5 => array("day" => "2013-01-03", "delay" => 9),
);
$a=array();
foreach ($raw as $r) {
    if ($r["delay"]>0) {$a[$r["day"]]++;}
}

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
print "$k = $v<br>";
}

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
 $sum[]=array("day"=>$k, "misses" => $v);
}
print_r($sum);
```

Returns

```
Array (
 [0] => Array ( [day] => 2013-01-01 [misses] => 2 )
 [1] => Array ( [day] => 2013-01-02 [misses] => 1 )
 [2] => Array ( [day] => 2013-01-03 [misses] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: So lovely to have people downvoting without giving any feedback. Thank you guys.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't me... upvoting to counter :P I'll take a look at this thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_walk function, but I suppose the only thing you need is:

```
    $unique_days = array();
    foreach ($raw as $row) {
if (!isset($unique_days[$row['day']])) $unique_days[$row['day']] = 0; -- place 1
      if ($row['delay'] > 0) {
if (!isset($unique_days[$row['day']])) $unique_days[$row['day']] = 0; -- place 2
        $unique_days[$row['day']]++
      }
    }
```

it will store only unique days with proper counter

UPDATE check places 1 and 2 - first one is needed if you need all days in final array, second is needed if you need only unique days and don't want warning

Comment: You just copy-pasted the code in question and haven't added anything new.

Comment: @AmalMurali you're wrong, I've added 1 line and explained that other calls are not needed